# Problem printing from HP Deksjet D2666

Tags: 13.10, printing

i use ubuntu 13.10 and use hp deksjet d2666 printer but only tri colour cartridge work well, so i can't print in black, what should i do to activate the black cartridge? thank you for the answer ...

Comment: I am not sure, based on the wording, if you are having an issue with the cartridge or Ubuntu. You should be able to choose to print in greyscale only which should use the black cartridge. If the cartridge itself is empty then it needs to be replaced.

Comment: i have choose to print in greyscale and black only but it doesn't work. i try to use the printer with another os and it work. the cartridge is new.